# Encrypting password string in C++

Tags: encryption, c++

I have a client server based application where user is presented with login screen in the client. It then passes the credentials to the server which does the authentication. Client-server communication happens via a web service hosted on the server using https protocol (with TLS1.2 support). Client passes username and password to the web service. I am thinking of encrypting the password evethough I am using https based communication. My questions are:

1. Is it worthwhile to do a second level of encryption for password?
2. Is there any good practices to follow (like which algorithm to use etc)?
3. Its a MFC based application written in C++. Does windows provide any methods to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, you shouldn't encrypt the password on the client if the transmission of data is secured.**

If you got it all perfect, you're not likely to add any security to the process.

If you don't get it perfect, you might be introducing a new vulnerability (buffer overflow, oracle attack, etc).

If the TLS version you're using somehow gets compromised, then you have MUCH bigger problem that leaking password in transit.

You shouldn't hash the password either (for the same reasons as above).

Note that there is a special case: you might want you login process to go through a [challenge-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) system, even if you're using TLS, in order to require a [proof of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) from the caller. For some specialized services, that might help in alleviate DOS attacks trying to overload the authentication component (although there is a debate whether the effectiveness of that measure in the field and whether it's worth the effort compared to other DOS counter-measures).

Comment: From what I can see, there is *problem* with the challenge-response: the secret (password) cannot be hashed on the server side since it is part of the challenge token...